# Copy col in csv to another csv and insert 3 blanks rows after each row

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am pretty new to python. Though I have read hundreds of posts regarding copying column from one csv to another csv, I still cannot get the right result.

I want: 1. copying column 5 from file a to file b.
        2. insert 3 blank rows after each row

For example, if col 5 has:

```
1
2
3
```

I want:

```
1
blank
blank
blank
2
blank
blank
blank
3
blank
blank
blank
```

I wrote something but not sure if it is correct:

```
 with open (score_data,'rb') as a, open(new_score,'wb') as b:
    ca=csv.reader(a)
    ca_rows=list(a)
    cb=csv.writer(b)

    for line, row in enumerate(a,start=1):
        b.writerow([row[0],row[0]])

        if line % 4 == 0:
            b.writerrow([])
```

Thanks for helping me

Edit:
Thanks Mustermann. I figure out how to add three blank row after copying the original data:

```
     with open (score_data) as a, open(new_score,'w') as b:
            b.write(next(a))
            ca=csv.reader(a, delimiter=',')
            ca_rows=list(a)
            cb=csv.writer(b)

            for row in range(len(ca_rows)):
                cb.writerow(([" "]*3)+[ca_rows[row][-2]]) # replace -2 with actual col if delimiter is working
                cb.writerow([" "]*3)
```

However, the data was copied to column 4 in the new file. I want the data to be copied to column 6 in the new file. Any idea? Thanks

Another issue: my modified code is able to copy the number but not any word.
For example, if my input file shows:

```
1
2
MO
3
```

Now the output shows:

```
1
blank
blank
blank
2
blank
blank
blank
O
blank
blank
blank
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First this is an incomplete answer as i cant get this working from termux(android)

.py

```
score_data="s.csv"
new_score="n.csv"
import csv

with open (score_data) as a, open(new_score,'w') as b:
    ca=csv.reader(a, delimiter=',')
    ca_rows=list(a)
    cb=csv.writer(b)

    for row in range(len(ca_rows)):
        cb.writerow((["blank"]*4)+[ca_rows[row][-2]])# replace -2 with actual col if delimiter is working
        cb.writerow(["blank"]*5)
        cb.writerow(["blank"]*5)
        cb.writerow(["blank"]*5)
```

I cant get this delimiter working
But i think you might get the idea

s.csv

```
b ,b ,b ,b ,1
b ,b ,b ,b ,2
b ,b ,b ,b ,3
```

n.csv

```
blank,blank,blank,blank,1
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,2
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,3
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the script partially work. My script now copies content in column 5 in the original file to column 4 in the new file. Any idea? Thanks